# Sitecore Entity Service on version 9.3

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I have a Sitecore Entity Service implementation based on official documentation.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/create-an-entityservice.html

It was working fine on `version 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2`.
After upgrading the solution to 9.3, I cannot build the project anymore because `EntityService class` cannot be found in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastrucure.Sitecore assembly`.

```
 public class SampleController : EntityService<Entity> {}
```

What should I change to make it working again?

Answer (score 2):

You should derive your controller from EntityServiceBase instead of EntityService.

```
public class SampleController : Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Services.EntityServiceBase<Entity>
```

After this change, you will be able to build the code and use your entity service